# How to remove a span from list by span's class name by jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm dynamically appending a `span` class to an `li` element

```
li_element.append("<span class='delay_loading'><img id='delay_ajax-loader' style='display:none;' src='/static/img/ajax-delay.gif' /></span>")
```

How can I remove the added `span` class by its class name?

Comment: you want to remove class attribute or complete span ???

Answer (score 5):

`$('.delay_loading').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you just have to `find()` it first. Because you know that it'll be a direct child of the li_element, you can use `children()` which will be faster:

```
li_element.children(".delay_loading").remove();
```

However, a better idea might be to keep a reference to it in the first place:

```
var span = $("<span class='delay_loading'><img ... ></span>").appendTo(li_element);

// later, when your loading is done:
span.remove();
```